# How to differentiate model classes between webapp and unittest

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've started looking in to unittest when using google app engine. And it seems to bit tricky from what I've read. Since you can't (and not suppose to) run your test's against the datastore.

I've written an abstract class to emulate a datastore model class. And it quite works pretty nice returning mockup data on get, all, fetch and so on (only tried on a small scale) returning dbModel like results.

The one thing I haven't found a solution I'm satisfied with is how to differentiate which model class to use. I want to use the mock-ups for unit tests and the actual db.Model for when webapp is running.

My current solution looks like this in my .py containing all db.Models:

```
if 'SERVER_SOFTWARE' in os.environ:
    class dbTest(db.Model):
        content = db.StringProperty()
        comments = db.ListProperty(str)
else:
    class dbTest(Abstract):
        content = 'Test'
        comments = ['test1', 'test2']
```

And it kinda feels like it could break any minute. Is this the way to go or could one combine these as one class and if the db.Model is invoked properly use that else the mockup?

Comment: PLEASE don't call a variable `list`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [gaetestbed](https://github.com/jgeewax/gaetestbed) ([docs](http://gaetestbed.geewax.org/index.html)). It stubs out the datastore (and all the other services like memcache) and makes testing from the command line very easy. It ensures a clean environment before every test runs.

I personally think it is nicer than the other solutions I have seen.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll look in to it.

Comment: I ended up using this solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of messing your `models.py` I would go with [gaeunit](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit).

I've used it with success in a couple of projects and the features I like are:

1. Just one file to add to your project (gaeunit.py) and you are almost done
2. Gaeunit isolates the test datastore from the development store (i.e. tests don't pollute your development db)

Comment: Thanks, I looked at if before. But felt it was kinda messy running all my test from a browser and most of all I want to separate the logic of what's happening. But I missed the part of separated datastores which is nice. Maybe it's the way to go.

Comment: look [here](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit/wiki/Readme), you can run your tests from commandline in some way. What do you mean with "to separate the logic of what's happening"?

Comment: for some test it's not important how the data came about, just how to deal with the data types. Let's say I want to manipulate one property based on the value of another property of the same object. I want to be able to run the same code as if in the webapp but the test it self should care about how it got it's data. I feel to involve a real datastore in my test would create an overhead of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

> Since you can't (and not suppose to)
>   run your test's against the datastore.

This is not true. You can and should use the local datastore implementation as a test harness - there's no reason to waste your time creating mocks for every datastore behaviour. You can use a tool such as noseGAE or gaeunit, as suggested by other posters, but if you want to set it up yourself, see [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/186251).

Comment: I always thought that was the difference between unittest and implementation tests, but I stand corrected. Thanks for the link

Comment: We've based our App Engine tests here at work on the WebTest (http://pythonpaste.org/webtest/) and Nick's snippet.  They work great for us.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one problem you're trying to address here...

First, for running tests with GAE emulation you can take a look at [gaeunit](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit/), which I like best. If you don't want to run them from the browser then you can take a look at [noseGAE](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/NoseGAE/0.1.3) (part of [nose](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose)). This should give you command-line testing.

Second, regarding your comment about about 'creating an overhead of dependencies' it sounds like you're searching for a good unit testing and mocking framework. These will let you mock out the database for tests which don't need to hit it. Try [mox](http://code.google.com/p/pymox/) and [mockito for python](http://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/).